# "Missing type specifier int assumed" C++ Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have the following problem: This error appeared to me, when I compiled the source code:

`error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed`

This error occurs when a variable is not initialized with any type (like a integer, float or any custom type of object). But, I have a type initialized and it's not recognizable, although I have more classes, which are similarly built like the trouble one, and they're running fine.

So, my problematic class is the following one:

```
class Rectangle
{
    float x1, y1, x2, y2;
    bool created;

public:
    Rectangle() { created = false;}
    Rectangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
    ~Rectangle() {}
    bool isCreated() { return created;}
    void setCreated( bool c) { created = c;}
    float getX1() { return x1;}
    float getX2() { return x2;}
    float getY1() { return y1;}
    float getY2() { return y2;}
};
```

An example of a working class:

```
class Triangle
{
private:
    vector<float> x, y, z;
    bool created;

public:
    Triangle() { created = false;}
    Triangle(vector<float> x, vector<float> y, vector<float> z);
    ~Triangle() {}
    bool isCreated() { return created;}
    void setCreated( bool c) { created = c;}
    vector<float> getX() { return x;}
    vector<float> getY() { return y;}
    vector<float> getZ() { return z;}
};
```

Finally, the code fragment where the errors occur:

```
class Primitive
{
private:
    string index;
    Material mat;
    Texture text;
    int count;
    Rectangle rect; //error detected in this line
    Triangle tri;
    Cylinder cyl;
    Sphere sph;
    Torus tor;

public:
    Primitive() {count = 0;}
    Primitive(string id, Material mt, Texture tx);
    ~Primitive(void);
    string getIndex() { return index;}
    Material getMaterial() { return mat;}
    Texture getTexture() { return text;}
    void addRectangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);     //error detected in this line
    Rectangle getRectangle() { if(rect.isCreated()) return rect; else return Rectangle(); }   //error detected in this line
    void addTriangle(float x1, float x2, float x3, float y1, float y2, float y3, float z1, float z2, float z3);
    Triangle getTriangle() { if(tri.isCreated()) return tri; else return Triangle(); }
    void addCylinder(float bs, float tp, float hei, int sli, int stac);
    Cylinder getCylinder() { if(cyl.isCreated()) return cyl; else return Cylinder(); }
    void addSphere(float rad, int sli, int stac);
    Sphere getSphere() { if(sph.isCreated()) return sph; else return Sphere(); }
    void addTorus(float in, float out, int sli, int loo);
    Torus getTorus() { if(tor.isCreated()) return tor; else return Torus(); }
};
```

Any ideas about how to correct it?

EDIT: My includes are:

```
#include "Material.h" //custom class
#include "Texture.h"  //custom class
#include <iostream>
```

The compiler is `Visual C++ 2010`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from a really bad design, there are no actual *errors* in the code you've shown. My guess is that the error is in code you haven't shown us.

My personal guess is that either `Rectangle` or `rect` somehow don't mean what you expect them to mean at the point you're using them. Perhaps someone has been playing tricks with the preprocessor.

I'm absolutely certain that there is no erroneous code of any kind in what you've presented here. I've edited your code lightly, and it compiles perfectly:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Rectangle
{
    float x1, y1, x2, y2;
    bool created;

public:
    Rectangle() { created = false;}
    Rectangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
    ~Rectangle() {}
    bool isCreated() { return created;}
    void setCreated( bool c) { created = c;}
    float getX1() { return x1;}
    float getX2() { return x2;}
    float getY1() { return y1;}
    float getY2() { return y2;}
};

class Triangle
{
private:
    ::std::vector<float> x, y, z;
    bool created;

public:
    Triangle() { created = false;}
    Triangle(::std::vector<float> x, ::std::vector<float> y, ::std::vector<float> z);
    ~Triangle() {}
    bool isCreated() { return created;}
    void setCreated( bool c) { created = c;}
    ::std::vector<float> getX() { return x;}
    ::std::vector<float> getY() { return y;}
    ::std::vector<float> getZ() { return z;}
};

class Primitive
{
private:
    ::std::string index;
//    Material mat;
//    Texture text;
    int count;
    Rectangle rect; //error detected in this line
    Triangle tri;
//    Cylinder cyl;
//    Sphere sph;
//    Torus tor;

public:
    Primitive() {count = 0;}
//    Primitive(::std::string id, Material mt, Texture tx);
    ~Primitive(void);
    ::std::string getIndex() { return index;}
//    Material getMaterial() { return mat;}
//    Texture getTexture() { return text;}
    void addRectangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);     //error detected in this line
    Rectangle getRectangle() { if(rect.isCreated()) return rect; else return Rectangle(); }   //error detected in this line
    void addTriangle(float x1, float x2, float x3, float y1, float y2, float y3, float z1, float z2, float z3);
    Triangle getTriangle() { if(tri.isCreated()) return tri; else return Triangle(); }
//    void addCylinder(float bs, float tp, float hei, int sli, int stac);
//    Cylinder getCylinder() { if(cyl.isCreated()) return cyl; else return Cylinder(); }
//    void addSphere(float rad, int sli, int stac);
//    Sphere getSphere() { if(sph.isCreated()) return sph; else return Sphere(); }
//    void addTorus(float in, float out, int sli, int loo);
//    Torus getTorus() { if(tor.isCreated()) return tor; else return Torus(); }
};
```

Comment: "playing tricks with the preprocessor" — as in missing include? :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Yes. More or less. I'm imagining that somewhere in the resulting 'translation unit', after all the includes have been processed, that there is a `#define` for `rect` or `Rectangle` that isn't `#undef`ed before the `Primitive` class is defined. My guess would be `rect` because otherwise I would expect the definition of `Rectangle` to raise holy havoc.

Comment: can your compiler preserve preprocessed source?

Comment: How can I see if it supports that functionality?

Comment: @VitorSantos: What compiler are you using? And just because no other code is generating an error doesn't mean that the code isn't a problem. Usually syntax errors are a result of things that are very near the syntax error. But sometimes they are a result of something you did that's far away from where the compiler detected the error. One of the biggest ways to make that happen is the preprocessor, which is why my suspicions lie in the direction they do. I repeat, there is no problem obvious in the code you've shown.

Comment: @VitorSantos: I've tested, and there is NO ERROR in the code you've pasted. It compiles perfectly for me. That means the problem must lie in code you haven't pasted.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `Rectangle` class is not defined before the `Primitive` in the translation unit.

Comment: Not only declared, but defined too.

Comment: @Pubby, I am not sure about the terms, but by declaration I didn't mean forward-declaration, what definition are you talking about? I can only think of members function definition (that is — implementation), which is not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, not sure if the term is correct, I just meant what you said - a forward definition isn't enough in this case.

Comment: Ah okay. So we both not sure about the terms, but agree on the matter :)

Comment: And a forward definition would result in an error about an incomplete type, not the error the OP is reporting.

Comment: @Pubby, I added `(completely)` to make it harder to misinterpret :)

Comment: Just looked it up in the standard: *"A class is considered deﬁned after the closing
brace of its class-speciﬁer has been seen even though its member functions are in general not yet deﬁned."*

Comment: The code I wrote is in the original order. The `Rectangle` class is defined before the `Primitive` one.